# Evaluate the integral using contour integration

Tags: contour-integration

Evaluate ∫$\frac{\cos2x}{(1−2a\cos x+a^2)}\,\mathrm dx$ from $0$ to $2π$

I need to evaluate the following
using contour integral given that |a|<1

I wrote $\cos2x$ as $\frac{1}{2}\bigl(\frac{z^4+1}{z^2}\bigr)$
,
And changed $\mathrm dx$ into $\mathrm dz/iz$,
by using $z^2=e^{2ix}$.

And later got stuck factorizing the integral,

Could anyone help me out with this